# Steelcase desk drawer stuck in unlocked position

Tags: drawers

I have a steelcase desk at work with a two drawer locking file attached to the underside of the desk. The lock is UNlocked. I can put the key in and turn it no problem...but the drawers won't open! If it was just "stuff" I would expect the lower drawer to open no problem, as it is a neatly organized file drawer. The smaller, upper drawer is full of random junk. I've tried locking/unlocking the drawer, wiggling the drawers, pulling hard, etc. Any thoughts on how to get the dang thing open? I've stuck a hanger in and wiggled it about to shift items. No luck. It opened this morning :(

Comment: Not really a home improvement question, and not something I can answer without seeing/feeling the mechanism.

Comment: Most of those, the lock is on a shaft.  You turn he key and then the whole lock assembly pops out an inch like a plunger.  Does yours pop out?

Answer (score 2):

There are anti tip mechanisms in steelcase desk drawers. 1.)Open center drawer all the way open. Looking under center drawer, far back on right & left edge are metal square shapes sticking up -try lifting its insert up (like a guillotine blade). How it works is when drawer closed a pin goes through this and slides freely, if tipped the guillotine drops down and prevents pin from pulling out) So by manually disengaging (lifting square up) should unlock it. The key thing is getting center drawer pulled open enough to access area. I will try and get some photos added. 
I figured it out after the steelcase desk drawers were opening fine, then we moved desk on its side, upside down so could slide it on a blanket etc and afterwards had locked drawers :-( But figured it out.